# Call function from viewmodel and update dao at specific time

Tags: android, kotlin

I have function reterns from repo to update habits as not completed,

```
    fun updateAllHabitsAsNotCompleted() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        updateAllHabitsAsNotCompletedUseCase()
    }
}
```

I want to get this function in fragment to update the habits every day at 3AM.
I used AlarmManger as inner class in the fragment but I want to create class for it to call it in manifests to work every day, This what I did

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class HabitsFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentHabitBinding>() {
.......
.......

inner class HabitAlertReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        viewModel.updateAllHabitsAsNotCompleted()
    }
}

private fun updateHabitsAsNotCompletedEveryDay() {
    val alarmManager = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val intent = Intent(requireContext(), HabitAlertReceiver::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        requireContext(),
        0,
        intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
        timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
        set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3)
        set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
        set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
    }
    alarmManager.setRepeating(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        calendar.timeInMillis,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
        pendingIntent
    )
  }
}
```

Any Idea for how can I update all the habits every day as notcompleted at specific time?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you thought about resetting them when the user opens the app instead? Have a `nextReset` timestamp stored, when the app starts check if that's in the past - if so, clear things and set `nextReset` to the next 3AM timestamp. It would be a lot easier, you wouldn't need to rely on alarms and permissions, and you could use your `ViewModel` logic as-is since it would be running in an `Activity`. Doing all this in the background but trying to go through a `ViewModel` makes this really complicated - if you *do* want a background task, just call directly whatever the VM is calling, go around it

Comment: @cactustictacs easy, simple, and great :D